# Redhat/CentOS Libraries to Ubuntu Libraries

Tags: 20.04

Hello Ubuntu Community,

I am new to the ubuntu suite coming from centOS.  I am trying to find these libraries in ubuntu from centos:

```
libX11
libX11-devel
openmotif
openmotif-deve
libXp
libXp-devel
gcc
gcc-c++
gcc-gfortran
libX11
libX11-devel
libXt-devel
libXext
libXp
libXp-devel
libXft-devel
libXtst-devel
xorg-x11-xbitmaps
flex
byacc
*fonts-ISO8859-*
```

These libraries are required for a program called GEMPAK (https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/gempak/doc/install.html)

If you could help me figure out which Ubuntu libraries correspond that would be very helpful.

Comment: What is your actual goal? Installing that program?

Comment: you can find the all here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/ Mind that gempak is available as a DEB so why bother?

Comment: Yes I would like to install GEMPAK on ubuntu. 
still  new to linux so what exactly is a DEB and how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compilation process maybe [avoided](https://github.com/Unidata/gempak) by using [binary](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/downloads/gempak/) deb-package:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-6/libgfortran3_6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-6/gcc-6-base_6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./gcc-6-base_6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb ./libgfortran3_6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb

wget https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/downloads/gempak/nawips-7.5.1/gempak-7.5.1.deb
sudo apt-get install ./gempak-7.5.1.deb
```

Comment: How to do call it afterwards?

Comment: It depends. Check the package contents by `dpkg -L gempak` and then `grep` the results for *bin*aries, *include*s and so on.

Comment: So gempak is installed above my user account in /home/gempak.  Is there a way to download it under my user account?  ie. /home/username/gempak?

Comment: I do not know actually. Ask package maintainers. You want it to be installed, we did it. Launch it and enjoy :)